# set -- $(cat /proc/loadavg)

Tags: bash, munin

Hi I have a munin plugin that does this

```
load_fetch()  {
set -- $(cat /proc/loadavg)
cat <<EOF                                                                                                                                                                           
load1.value $1                                                                                                                                                                      
load5.value $2                                                                                                                                                                      
load15.value $3                                                                                                                                                                     
EOF                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

I was woundering if any one could tell me what the "set --" is doing? its not an east thing to google for and get results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html has an explanation. This command (re)sets the argument variables ($1, $2, $3, $4 and $5 in this case). `cat /proc/loadavg` gives you a line with some numbers, feeding the output to `set --` maps those numbers to the $N-variables.

See for instance:

```
$ echo $1 $2

$ set -- HELLO WORLD
$ echo $1
HELLO
$ echo $2
WORLD
```

Comment: so using something like this is not likely to affect anything else on a machine? it is only going to affect the current script that is running? any way resetting the $1, $2 can leak out to other processes I assume this will not set something globally on a machine?

Comment: Correct. This script does not change anything on a global level. Changing environment variables in a shell only affects other processes started from that same shell, but in this case, even that won't happen, as $1, $2 and so on get reset when starting a new process.

Answer (score 2):

"Set --" is a bash clause and therefore not specific to munin. Getting to the bash help for the set parameter you can find this:

--  If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters are unset. 
    Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the arguments, 
    even if some of them begin with a `-'.

In your specific case, what it does is map/pass on the contents of cat/proc/loadavg as parameters $1 $2 and $3 so afterwars they can assign them to load1.value, load5.value and load15.value respectively

For further info use man or the following url: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html